# How to measure a BC-547 transistor's details?

Tags: transistors, current-measurement, multimeter, voltage-measurement, npn

I am new in electronics.

What I am trying to do is measuring everything of BC-547 transistor's details from a basic circuit design practically. I want to measure as example: collector-emitter voltage, emitter-ground voltage, base-ground voltage, base-emitter voltage etc.

This is the diagram. I connected everything correctly.I got it in my text book. I used as base resistor 1 mega ohm and collector resistor 1 kilo ohm.

[image: The npn transistor circuit]

Now, I can not understand how to measure them practically by multimeter (instead of theoretical formula). Any help please ?

Comment: What are you having problems with - it seems obvious what you should do but I'm not in your shoes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert base and collector resistances where appropriate, and for simple 2 wire measurements:

1. V1 and V2 are voltage sources.
2. AM1 and AM2 are ammeters.
3. VM1 and VM2 are voltmeters.

for minimum instrument measurement errors, the resistance of the voltmeters should be very high and the resistance of the ammeters should be very low.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

This is probably a little easier to visualize:

[image]